# Find phrase in a sentence

Tags: python, nltk

I must make a program which must find a phrase in a sentence with a user specified keyword:

```
The Large Hadron Collider (LHC) is the world’s largest and most powerfulparticle accelerator.This site includes the latest news from the project, accessible explanations of how the LHC works, how it is funded, who works there and what benefits it brings us.You can access a wide range of resources for the public, journalists and teachers and students, there are also many links to other sources of information.The Large Hadron Collider atCERNnear Geneva, Switzerland is opening new vistas on the deepest secrets of the universe, stretching the imagination with newly discovered forms of matter, forces of nature, and dimensions of space.
```

The user specifies:

```
['large', 'big', 'heavy']
```

Im not sure how to pick up a few words before and after the keyword in a variable
for example:

```
keyword = 'large'
```

it must return

```
The Large Hadron
```

as large is present in the sentence. How can i put one word before and one word after any variable in a sentence?

Answer (score 3):

```
test_word = 'large'
my_string = 'The Large Hadron Collider (LHC) is the world’s largest and most powerfulparticle accelerator.This site includes the latest news from the project, accessible explanations of how the LHC works, how it is funded, who works there and what benefits it brings us' 
# I truncated your sentence

test_words = my_string.lower().split()
correct_case = my_string.split() # this will preserve the case of the original words
# and it will be identical in length to test words with each word in the same position
position = test_words.index(test_word)

my_new_string = ' '.join(correct_case[position-1:position+2]
```

To be clear the two lists have the same words, the test_words list though keeps everything in lower case but your test_word will be in the same position in each list so you can use the position in the test_word list to pull the correct words from the correct_case list.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `index` to get the position of the keyword, then slicing the string one word on either side of the keyword.

```
In [1]: s = 'The Large Hadron Collider (LHC) is the world’s largest and most powerfulparticle accelerator.'
In [2]: words = s.split() 
In [3]: words_lower = s.lower().split() #lowercase words so keyword matching is easy.
In [4]: keyword = 'large'
In [5]: i = words_lower.index(keyword)
In [6]: phrase = ' '.join(words[i-1:i+2])
In [7]: phrase
Out[7]: 'The Large Hadron'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "The Large Hadron Collider (LHC) is the world’s largest and most powerfulparticle accelerator.This site includes the latest news from the project, accessible explanations of how the LHC works, how it is funded, who works there and what benefits it brings us.You can access a wide range of resources for the public, journalists and teachers and students, there are also many links to other sources of information.The Large Hadron Collider atCERNnear Geneva, Switzerland is opening new vistas on the deepest secrets of the universe, stretching the imagination with newly discovered forms of matter, forces of nature, and dimensions of space."
keywords = ['large', 'is', 'most']
text = text.lower().split(' ')
results = []
for word in keywords:
    indx = text.index(word)
    results.append(" ".join(text[indx-1:indx+2]))

print results
```